# Setting a subview delegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

Just out of curiosity, how can I set the delegate of all subviews using a for loop?

```
for case let i  in (myTest.popoverPresentationController?.presentedViewController.view.subviews)! 
{
   //how do i set the delegate of i?
   i.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Since UIView doesn't have a delegate, you'd have to cast it to your custom class.

Comment: if possible, can you please provide an example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
if let subviews = myTest.popoverPresentationController?.presentedViewController.view.subviews {
    for view in subviews {
        if let customView = view as? CustomView {
            customView.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To the downvoters: why don't you explain your reason and try to improve the answer?